# Dynamic pop-up menu in GUII matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-gui

I have created a GUI which saves value to the matlab file, then I wanted other GUI to show a list from 1 to 'n' in pop-up menu, and my question is how to do that? How could I create a dynamic pop-up menu which will display the list from 1 to, for example 5 or 10, depending on the value included in previous GUI?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What have you tried so far?  Also, check out the tour at http://stackoverflow.com/tour for tips on asking questions in a way that will be likely to get good answers (you get a badge for reading the tour, as well :) ).

Comment: A tip is to start by creating a static pop-up menu using a literal to set the fields. Then you can continue from there. Try to change the literal to a variable and then try to assign the variable with the correct values. In case you want more help than this you need to narrow the question down by showing your attmepts.